# AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation() is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, deep-linking

Firebase AppInvite has been deprecated and I have to update the code.

Library: `com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.6.2`

Code:

```
   private void handleDeepLink() {
        GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mActivity)
                .enableAutoManage(mActivity, this)
                .addApi(AppInvite.API)
                .build();

        AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, mActivity, false)
                .setResultCallback(
                        new ResultCallback<AppInviteInvitationResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResult(@NonNull AppInviteInvitationResult result) {
                                if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                    Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
                                    sDeepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);

                                    //...
                                } else {
                                    //...
                                }
                            }
                        });
    }
```

Do you know the new code?

Answer (score 3):

Following the documentation this is the new code to get the deep links.

Documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/android/receive

Code:

```
            FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
                .getDynamicLink(mActivity.getIntent())
                .addOnSuccessListener(mActivity, new OnSuccessListener<PendingDynamicLinkData>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(PendingDynamicLinkData pendingDynamicLinkData) {
                        Uri deepLink;
                        if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null) {
                            deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.getLink();
                            if (deepLink != null) {
                                //...
                            }
                        }
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(mActivity, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        //...
                    }
                });
```

Comment: So no need for the `.enableAutoManage(mActivity, this).addApi(AppInvite.API)` part?